# Why SMTP library(in python) using SMTP protocol to send email from Gmail to Gmail?

Tags: python, http, email, smtp

I want to write code in python that sending email from gmail to gmail, after I searched the internet I saw that there is SMTP library and it using SMTP protocol.

I know that Gmail using HTTP and not SMTP.

Why we need to use SMTP protocol to send email from Gmail(HTTP) to another Gmail(Http)?

Comment: It's SMTP, not STMP.

Comment: HTTP is used by the web interface to Gmail; it's not used for sending mail from one address to another.

Comment: So what Gmail using to sending mail from one anddress to another?

Comment: It's probably using SMTP, though internally it may use something entirely different if you are sending from one Gmail address to another. But you if are sending a message from `me@gmail.com` to `you@somewhereelse.org`, SMTP is (probably) the protocol that Gmail and SomewhereElse use to talk to each other.

Comment: The web interface you see isn't *all* there is to Gmail. You can use a different client (Apple Mail, Thunderbird, mutt, etc) if you want, and *it* would connect to Gmail using either POP or IMAP. There is a difference between the user interface to Gmail and the mail service behind it.

Comment: You might just want to read the [Wikipedia article on SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Comment: (Regarding my previous comment, an e-mail client will use either POP or IMAP to *retrieve* messages, but will also use SMTP to *send* a new message via Gmail.)

Comment: As I know a mail that pass between gmail to gmail dosent use SMTP protocol, am I wrong?

Comment: "Between gmail and gmail" doesn't really make sense outside of the implementation of the Gmail service. Unless you work for Google, Gmail is essentially a single black box. Internally, individual machines *might* use SMTP; there's no externally visible way to know, and if you are writing code to interface with Gmail, it doesn't matter one way of the other. You just need SMTP to send messages *to* Gmail.